# R sorting using simple codes

Tags: r, sorting, date, conditional-statements

Can someone help me with the below problem?

Dataset sample:

```
Ticketid    Creation_Date   Location    Person
a1  01-02-2015  A   John
b1  03-02-2015  B   Jack
c1  03-02-2015  C   Mint
a1  03-02-2015  D   Manu
d1  03-02-2015  A   Somu
e1  03-02-2015  A   John
b1  11-02-2015  B   Jack
a1  11-02-2015  C   Mint
b1  14-02-2015  F   John
b1  27-02-2015  E   John
```

Problem:

1.Remove duplicates of Ticketid is filtered in such a way
                 ->creationdate is less than 7 days of the first occurence date.
For eg: For ticket id,"a1", there are 3 creation dates namely, "01-02-2015,03-02-2015,11-02-2015", I wanted a new column has "repeat flag" and flag the first occurence in this case being 01-02-2015 as Yes. Because the second occurence is within 7 days of the first incident.

2.By the above logic,

```
                ->I want to filter by Location(Ticketid,creationdate)
                ->I want to filter by Person(Ticketid,creationdate)
```

Code:

t.first <- eg1[match(unique(eg1$Ticketid), eg1$Ticketid),]

How to save the output in same excel sheet and do conditional formatting for locations/engineers who have more than 1 incident?

Code I tried was too basic, requesting someone's help asap.Thanks in advance.

Add-on to clarify the query better:

Input:

Ticketid  Creation_Date   Location    Person  Partused    deviceused

```
a1  01-02-2015  A   John    Monitor     Model1
b1  03-02-2015  B   Jack    Keyboard    Model2
c1  03-02-2015  C   Mint    cable       Model3
a1  03-02-2015  D   Manu    Monitor     Model1
d1  03-02-2015  A   Somu    Motherboard Model2
e1  03-02-2015  A   John    Motherboard Model2
b1  11-02-2015  B   Jack    cable       Model2
a1  11-02-2015  C   Mint    Keyboard    Model3
b1  14-02-2015  F   John    Motherboard Model1
b1  27-02-2015  E   John    Motherboard Model3
```

I want my output in the below format as a table:

Repeat flag has many conditions:for now if the only condition is if the second time order is created within the seven days of the first order as in case of a1.

**The first creation date varies for every ticket id.**

```
Answer1:**Location  RepeatFlag  Model1  Model2  Model3**

Answer2:**Location  Person  RepeatFlag  Model1  Model2  Model3**

Answer3:**Location  PartsUsed   RepeatFlag  Model1  Model2  Model3**
```

Note:This is just a sample of dynamically changing varied rows. So kindly share a code tip which satisfies any kind of input as I would expect this to be automated process whereby this report is automatically mailed as excel report once the data gets refreshed in the source(excel sheet).

Kindly throw a light how we can automate this as well.

Thanks for the support provided.Much appreciated.

Regards,
VK

Comment: I've edited your Q so your data is better formatted - please read StackOverflow's formatting language instructions.

Comment: Thanks Sir.It would be great if someone can throw light.

Comment: Could you post the expected output?  Are you only checking the condition (less than 7) between the 1st and the 2nd dates for each grouping variable?

Comment: Hi, I have updated my query in the question asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question:

```
df <- data.frame(Ticketid = c('a1','b1','c1','a1','d1','e1','b1','a1','b1','b1'), 
Creation_Date = as.Date(c('01-02-2015','03-02-2015','03-02-2015','03-02-2015','03-02-2015','03-02-2015','11-02-2015','11-02-2015','14-02-2015','27-02-2015'), format = '%d-%m-%Y'), 
Location = c('A','B','C','D','A','A','B','C','F','E'), 
Person = c('John','Jack','Mint','Manu', 'Somu','John', 'Jack', 'Mint','John','John') )

   Ticketid Creation_Date Location Person
1        a1    2015-02-01        A   John
2        b1    2015-02-03        B   Jack
3        c1    2015-02-03        C   Mint
4        a1    2015-02-03        D   Manu
5        d1    2015-02-03        A   Somu
6        e1    2015-02-03        A   John
7        b1    2015-02-11        B   Jack
8        a1    2015-02-11        C   Mint
9        b1    2015-02-14        F   John
10       b1    2015-02-27        E   John

library(dplyr)

first_creation <- df %>% 
select(Ticketid,First_Date = Creation_Date) %>% 
group_by(Ticketid) %>% 
slice(1) %>% 
ungroup()

df2 <- merge(first_creation,df, all.y = T, by = 'Ticketid')

df3 <- df2 %>% mutate(time_diff = Creation_Date - First_Date)


df_flagged <- df3 %>% group_by(Ticketid) %>% mutate(Within_7 = ifelse(time_diff > 7 | time_diff == 0, 'NO','YES'))

    Source: local data frame [10 x 7]
Groups: Ticketid

   Ticketid First_Date Creation_Date Location Person time_diff Within_7
1        a1 2015-02-01    2015-02-01        A   John    0 days       NO
2        a1 2015-02-01    2015-02-03        D   Manu    2 days      YES
3        a1 2015-02-01    2015-02-11        C   Mint   10 days       NO
4        b1 2015-02-03    2015-02-03        B   Jack    0 days       NO
5        b1 2015-02-03    2015-02-11        B   Jack    8 days       NO
6        b1 2015-02-03    2015-02-14        F   John   11 days       NO
7        b1 2015-02-03    2015-02-27        E   John   24 days       NO
8        c1 2015-02-03    2015-02-03        C   Mint    0 days       NO
9        d1 2015-02-03    2015-02-03        A   Somu    0 days       NO
10       e1 2015-02-03    2015-02-03        A   John    0 days       NO
```

Comment: Thank you Gentleman,kindly find the updated query.This did satisfy my problem partially.

Comment: I get the below error when I process the first few lines.                         Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: You will need to install the package 'dplyr' by typing in install.packages('dplyr')

Comment: col.slade:  This code when used in the huge datset, I get the below error message which results in "NA" as output for time_diff and within_7 variables". I read the file as csv and then computed this. Warning message:
In Ops.factor(c(25L, 4L, 7L, 22L, 59L, 3L, 40L, 37L, 34L, 25L, 48L,  :
  ‘-’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: After I installed library(date) and library(timeDate), the codes worked but I find a new error where timedifference is in huge numbers like "86400".  Example:                                                                    Asset First_Date SER. Creation_Date Branch Engineer_Name time_diff Within_7
10k 03-03-2015 84901926444 04-03-2015 ND Mani 86400 NO